# Displays all errors at one time NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I have problem display errors at one time, When comparePassword is incorrect and when req.check is incorrectly inserted. Please, can someone help me with the improvement of this??

```
router.put('/changePassword', function (req, res, next) {

User.comparePassword(req.body.old, req.user.password, function (err, isMatch) {
req.check('old', 'Old password is required').notEmpty();
req.check('new', 'New password is incorrect').isLength({ min: 4 }).equals(req.body.newConfirm);

  var errors = req.validationErrors();


      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
          bcrypt.hash(req.body.new, saltRounds, function (err, hash) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
              var newPassword = hash;
                  User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user._id },
                    {
                      $set: { 
                        password: newPassword,
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      upsert: true
                    },
                    ((newPassword) => {
                      res.send(newPassword)
                    })
                  )
                } 
    })

  } else {
        res.json('Old password is wrong')
  }}
  )})
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check in your `if (err)` that errors is not null or undefined (or the other way around), then you can create a variable that will contain your errors (new object with `{err, errors}`?) and throw it